# rigidbody.MovePosition(rb.position + offset) makes falling slowly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want move my character with MovePosition, but when i write this, my characters falling very slowly

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + offset); //offset this vector2(x,0)
```

P.S. This method of movement is good for implement character movement? If i change rigidbody.position i have a many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[RigidBody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) is the way to go for changing the position when a gameobject has a Rigidbody component attached.
If you need a more precise physics simulation, you may operate with forces using [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

Returning to your problem, the object is falling slowly because the offset's x is too small.
You may calculate it as:

```
float y = speed * Time.DeltaTime // In case you use FixedUpdate then Time.FixedDeltaTime
Vector3 offset = Vector3.down * y;
```